# How to implement a button into Simulink Subsystem Mask?

Tags: matlab, simulink, masking

As I need to specify a local variable to a Subsystem, I created a mask. Doing that I lose the easy access to the subsystem. Right-click and navigating to "Look under mask" is supposed to be too complicated.

So I thought about a workaround and built the following:

[image: mask]

The dialog callback code behind the *"Get deeper!"* checkbox is:

```
myParameter = %Parameter set by checking Get deeper!
path = gcb(gcs);

if strcmp(get_param(gcb,'myParameter'),'on')    
open_system(path,'tab');
end
```

Everytime when I check the box, the subsystem gets opened and also by every double click on the subsystem, in case the box was checked before. Hence the code does what it should, but thats actualy not the common way how one would realize/visualize something like this.

What I want is a button "Look under mask" in my mask - so the subsystem just gets opened by clicking on that button. Basically the button should call the function: `open_system(gcb(gcs),'tab')`. Looks so easy, but Simulink doesn't offer me any option to implement this. Can anybody help?

The main issue whith the current solution is also that with every execution of the model all subsystems open up, where the box is checked. That's not the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab 2012b adds exactly what you want: masked blocks have a button on the botton left that is a shortcut to "Look under mask".

Unfortunately, I don't think it is possible to add a button in a mask.

You may want to change your function to automatically set the "Get deeper!" checkbox off after the user clicks on it. That would avoid the automatic opening of the subsystems when the model is loaded. You could do that adding `set_param(path,'myParameter','off')` just after the `open_system(path,'tab');`

Finally, as another workaround, you may want to set the `OpenFcn` callback to call `open_system(gcb,'tab')`. This will make the system work as if it isn't masked at all. You can put two `open_system` calls, one to look under mask and the other to open the mask dialog box, if you prefer.

Comment: Really? I have Matlab 2013a and 2012a and both don't have the button ;) I also found this: [Is there a way to add another button to a mask in Simulink?](http://www.mathworks.de/support/solutions/en/data/1-2YEIGG/index.html?product=SL) which works fine for plots, but not for my case. What you suggested is what I'm trying to implenent for hours now. If you could provide some code you would help me a lot. I try "initialize" the checkbox as off, so it's unchecked everytime when I double click and for very simulation. But I'm not able to make it work.

Comment: @thewaywewalk it's the little down arrow in the bottom left corner of the masked subsystem. It was introduced in R2012b, see http://blogs.mathworks.com/seth/2012/09/12/welcome-simulink-r2012b/.

Comment: From the release notes: "The [look under mask] badge does not appear for masks of library links if the library is locked or its `LockLinksToLibrary` property is set to true."

Comment: @am304 - okay I found it, but anyway, it has to work under 2012a as well.

Comment: @nonDocur - why does `set_param(gcb,'myParameter','off')` in the Initialization tab not work?

Comment: @nonDocur your first suggestion I added to my question, as it has nothing to do with the actual answer. Furthermore i implementented `set_param(path,'myParameter','off')` within my if-condition, right after `open_system(...)`. You could add this to your answer, then its complete and I can accept it. To make it perfect I could need a command which closes the Dialog Box after enabling the checkbox. I just found `close_system` which then would close also the just opened Subsystem.

Comment: @thewaywewalk - AFAIK, to avoid infinite loops, Simulink does not allow set_param in the Initialization [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/initialize-mask.html#btlg32q-5).

Comment: @thewaywewalk - Again about the initialization code not working, I just found [an explanation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/mask-code-execution.html#btlgyb9-4) saying that Initializations are not run if the mask has no drawing commands.

Comment: @thewaywewalk - I did change my answer to add your suggestion. Thank you. Also, I do not know any means of closing an open mask dialog box.